# IBM API Connect - Sign in failed

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I did create APIConect service (Essential plan), but when I click on it from the Dashboard, then I'm stuck there. Obviously I did sign in the system (see screenshot), but the message said that the signing in failed.

I'm using Safari

[image]

Please help.

Thanks,
Bao

Answer (score 3):

The IBM API Connect service is based on the new Bluemix interface. Try to switch to that (clicking on "Try the new Bluemix
" on top left) before accessing the service instance (selecting APIs->API Connect within the new dashboard). I had the same issue and fixed it performing the above steps.

Moreover, try to start a new browser session (try private session or clear the cache and cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Some users have reported issues with logging in on Safari. Try Chrome or Firefox and see if that helps. We are looking into the underlying issue.